# Complete the circumference of circle on hover in svg

Tags: css, html, svg

What i am trynna do is half stroke gets completed of a  circle on hover of svg tag.

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="center">    
  <svg class="center" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="shap">
 <circle class="path-1" cx="65" cy="70" r=63 fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="#fff" />
    </g>

  </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```css
svg #shap{
 stroke-dasharray:200px;
 stroke-dashoffset:0%;
 transition:all 400ms;
}

svg:hover #shap{
 stroke-dasharray:400px;
 stroke-dashoffset:0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="center">    
  <svg class="center" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="shap">
 <circle class="path-1" cx="65" cy="70" r=63 fill="none" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" />
    </g>

  </svg>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 10/10 much better than my approach. I was working with an onmouseover event, but pseudo class is definitely the way to go.